# Complex numbers: why does this example take the real part of the denominator rather than the imaginary?

Tags: complex-analysis

In this example [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cTlR.jpg) , the last step of the proof shows the imaginary operation on the fraction after multiplying the numerator and denominator by the complex conjugate.
It appears the operation that occurred in the denominator was the real operation. What is the reasoning behind this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

$(1-re^{i\theta})(1-re^{-i\theta})=1+r^{2}e^{0}-re^{i\theta}-re^{-i\theta}=1+r^{2}-2r\cos \theta $. Since this is a real number  there is no need to take real or imaginary part of the denominator. You only have to take the imagibnary part of the numerator.